# Ocultar y mostrar un elemento con el mismo boton

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Al entrar a la web el elemento comienza estando oculto, y al presionar un boton lo muestro, como hago para que al volver a presionar el boton se vuelva a poner oculto ?

```
$(document).ready(main);

    $("#mostrar_fileupload_contrato").click(function(){
        $('#ArchivoContrato').show(1000,function() {

        });

});
```

Aca tengo el boton que muestra el file upload y el fileupload oculto

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id='mostrar_fileupload_contrato' style="margin-left: 10px">Subir contrato firmado</button>       


        <form>
         <div class="form-group" id="ArchivoContrato" style="display:none">
             <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Sube tu archivo</label>
             <input type="file" class="form-control-file"  >
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En lugar de usar `show()` puedes usar `toggle()` asi:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#mostrar_fileupload_contrato").click(function(){
        $('#ArchivoContrato').toggle(1000,function() {

        });
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id='mostrar_fileupload_contrato' style="margin-left: 10px">Subir contrato firmado</button>       


        <form>
         <div class="form-group" id="ArchivoContrato" style="display:none">
             <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Sube tu archivo</label>
             <input type="file" class="form-control-file"  >
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Buenisima respuesta y si quisiera agregar un elemento extra? para que se oculten / muestren dos ids

Comment: Seria igual.  Tambien puedes seleccionar varios elementos y separarlos por comas en tu selector `jQuery`.